# Media upload failure

Tags: wordpress, media-library

Cannot upload files into media library and receiving Err connection reset in Chrome console. We have upgraded WP to 5.7.1 and we are using PHP 7.2. Any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: Check the permissions on your uploads folder. It should be 755 and it should be owned by the server user (www-data).

Comment: Thanks Alex, I will do that and get back to you.